# Make ajax call after state change

Tags: redux

I want to implement checkbox-based filtering on my page. When I click on checkbox I want to change state and make ajax call based on checked items.

I have created `toggleCheckbox(id)` action and reducer that adds/removes id from selected items, but I have no idea where should I place ajax call.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Your component should dispatch the async action, to avoid duplicating the logic for toggling the selected items move it to the async action and change the normal action from toggle to set. Like this:

```
const toggleCheckbox = id => (dispatch, getState) => {
    const items = toggle(id, getState().selectedItems);
    dispatch(setSelectedItems(items));
    // call API with "items"
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Network calls are asynchronous, and actions are by default synchronous. They are just plain objets. To handle asynchronous behaviour you need a side-effect library like redux-sagas or redux-thunks. Take a look at https://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.html and https://redux-saga.js.org

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware that I have to use sagas or thunks. My problem is rather where should I make this ajax call - so I would have changed state.

Comment: From the thunk or the saga (whatever you using) you dispatch a success action and you pass the new data in the action payload. Then you use that payload in the reducer to mutate your state.